# Shared argument in constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr, initializer-list

I have this classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> p);
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> _p;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> p);
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> _p;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
private:
    A _a;
    B _b;
};
```

Both constructor arguments from `A` and `B` share the same pointer reference `shared_ptr`. In this case:

- How would be the best way of initializing `Foo`?
- Is it still possible to use a initialization list in `Foo`s constructor?

I am confused, because since both classes need the same `shared_ptr`instance, I would have to store that pointer somewhere, and I don't think that is possible with initialization lists.

Also, if the initialization occurs in the body of the constructor, it implies that both `A` and `B` should have a `move` constructor, correct? Because I would have to do something like this:

```
Foo::Foo() //: Cannot use initializer list
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<SomeClass>(SomeClass());
    _a = A(ptr);
    _b = B(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I thought of a better solution. Create the `shared_ptr`, then delegate to a private constructor that will use it to construct `_a` and `_b`. (Credit to Zan Lynx for suggesting the use of a function parameter as temporary storage.)

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(): Foo(std::make_shared<SomeClass>()) {}
private:
    Foo(std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> ptr): _a(ptr), _b(ptr) {}
    A _a;
    B _b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize members in the body of the constructor. By the time the body starts executing, the members must have been initialized already. Hence, if you try to do this, the members will be default-constructed, and then you'll just be assigning to them. `A` and `B` don't have default constructors, so this won't compile.

If you can afford the increase in size, make the `shared_ptr` a member of `Foo` as well and use that.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(): _ptr(std::make_shared<SomeClass>()), _a(_ptr), _b(_ptr) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> _ptr;
    A _a;
    B _b;
};
```

Comment: I believe you could also give the Foo() constructor a default argument and use that as temp storage for the pointer.

Comment: @ZanLynx Clever! Although, you just inspired me to come up with an even better solution...

Answer (score 1):

Given the way you've defined your classes (i.e. no way to access the internal `shared_ptr`), I think your solution is fine.  But note that `A` and `B` will required default constructors.  That's how they are initialized before you enter the constructor body.

Also, once you're in the constructor body, you will be doing **assignment**.  So both `A` and `B` will need an assignment operator.

Also, I feel it's good practice to pass `std::shared_ptr` into functions (including constructors) as references.